# Proving theorems about inductive types using _ind; App rule

Tags: coq

```
Variables A B : Prop.

Theorem proj1 : A /\ B -> A.
```

In order to learn, I'm trying to prove this theorem by explicitly writing down a proof term using `and_ind`.

I would assume the correct proof term is

```
fun (H : A /\ B) => and_ind A B A (fun a _ => a) H
```

But this raises an error, and instead the correct term is

```
fun (H : A /\ B) => and_ind (fun a _ => a) H
```

---

I don't understand this. The definition of `and_ind` is

```
and_ind = 
fun (A B P : Prop) (f : A -> B -> P) (a : A /\ B) => match a with
                                                     | conj x x0 => f x x0
                                                     end
     : forall A B P : Prop, (A -> B -> P) -> A /\ B -> P
```

How can I see from that that the parameters `(A B P : Prop)` have to be omitted?

The "App" rule

[image: App rule]

from the Reference Manual seems to state clearly that quantified variables have to be explicitly "instantiated" using the function application syntax that I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Coq, you can declare some arguments of a function as *implicit*.  When you call the function, you don't supply values for the implicit arguments; Coq automatically tries to infer suitable values, based on other information available during type checking.  The `A`, `B` and `P` arguments of `and_ind` are all declared as implicit, and can be inferred from the type of the `H` argument and the result type of the function argument.

You can see what arguments are considered implicit with the `About` command:

```
About and_ind.
(* and_ind : forall A B P : Prop, (A -> B -> P) -> A /\ B -> P *)

(* Arguments A, B, P are implicit *)
(* Argument scopes are [type_scope type_scope type_scope function_scope _] *)
(* and_ind is transparent *)
(* Expands to: Constant Coq.Init.Logic.and_ind *)
```

You can turn off implicit arguments with an individual call with an `@` sign:

```
Check fun A B H => @and_ind A B A (fun a _ => a) H.
(* fun (A B : Prop) (H : A /\ B) => and_ind (fun (a : A) (_ : B) => a) H *)
(*      : forall A B : Prop, A /\ B -> A *)
```

(Notice that Coq automatically omits implicit arguments when printing a term as well.)

The [Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-extensions.html#implicit-arguments) has more information on that subject.